# Springboot 1.5.1 migrate to 2.0.1 Instance format

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, gson

I want to migrate my springboot project from 1.5.1 to 2.0.1.

But the **Instant** format are different when I return the model in RestController.

Return object:

```
public class Message {
     private Instant instant;

}
```

In 1.5.1:

```
{
    "instant": {
         "epochSecond": 1537263091,
         "nano": 557000000
    }
}
```

In 2.0.1:

```
{
     "instant": "2018-09-18T09:46:02.646Z"
}
```

How can I get this one {
        "instant": {
             "epochSecond": 1537263091,
             "nano": 557000000
        }
    } when I use 2.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably set this operation on your application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

On the migration, if you added any of the following dependencies, try removing it:

```
jackson-modules-java8
jackson-datatype-jsr310
```

[UPDATED]

Another way, you could write a serializer for Instant:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

public class CustomInstantSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Instant o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(new EpochInstant(o));
    }

    public static class EpochInstant {

        private final long epochSecond;
        private final int nano;

        EpochInstant(Instant instant) {
            this.epochSecond = instant.getEpochSecond();
            this.nano = instant.getNano();
        }
    }
}
```

And have a Configuration class,  setting the Instant to use your serializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import java.time.Instant;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(Instant.class, new CustomInstantSerializer());

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: no. The date format in springboot 1.5.1 is not a timestamp format.  If you set it false, nothing will change.  If you set that property true, you will find the output is {"instant": 1537267373.794}.  What I want is a {"instant": {"epochSecond": 1537267373,"nano": 794000000}}

Comment: Well, great work.  I think it's fine for me to add @Configuration and JsonSerializer.  Also, I find some other methods like excluding the Jackson and using gson instead.  But I prefer your answer.  Thank you.